# Polling without timestamp

Tags: networking, polling

I currently have a requirement to conduct polling in a network where new systems may log into anytime.

The idea is that whoever comes online first goes into mode1 while the second guy goes into mode2, third guy and onwards to into mode3. Simple enough right, but the problem is deciding who came first.

Assume no third party online to make the decision for you [I am taking the worst case: Every other service explodes] and no time-sync. Also assume that the delay in transmission of data between the nodes is inconsistent and highly variable causing up-time to also not be reliable.

Since comments have a word limit, I'll reply here I guess:

gnat, I really don't understand the sharing my research part. Most resources on the net state relying on a server to see what logged in [No services is always running hence I can't rely on some external source to tell who logged in first] which completely isn't possible as like I mentioned you don't have any network you log into, you just log into your node.I thought of using a time-stamp, but due to the possibility of bad time-sync (past experience) it was shot down by my lead. Also, there is always the chance of 2 devices logging in at the same time. I am afraid what that could result in. Having an addition check after is doable, but not recommended [limited bandwidth]

Comment: I don't understand why you have a problem.  Who came first is whoever successfully logged in first.  The reliability of the system does not affect this decision whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, but the question lies who decides/what is used to decide who logged in first. There is no server you log into, its a more of a multi-node architecture where nodes are interacting with one another. The "login" as such is completely local to your device and not to any foreign server.

Comment: What operating system? Linux has the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) system call which does not involve timestamps (you just give a *delay* in milliseconds). But your question is unclear (we don't understand what *polling* means to you)

Comment: It sounds like you have a peer network where the peers, once connected, need to elect a "mode1", "mode2", etc. node.  Is this correct?

Comment: From your assumption "no third party online to make the decision for you and no time-sync" I think it is impossible to provide ordering. I think you need either a central entity *or* reliable timestamps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying, was caught up in something else. Yes, Dan that's exactly it.

Comment: I apparently cant edit my old comment (bad habit to press Enter). I apologize for the lack of clarity in my post. I mentioned the problem in using delay / up-time due to the erratic behavior of the network. arnoud, I understand what you mean. I ll try to look into Dan's answer first. Worst case hard code some stuff in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vaguely remember something like this from grad school many years ago.  You might want to do some googling for "peer networks" at the hardware level.

1. Every node broadcasts an "I am here" message every x time units
2. When starting up, the node quietly listens for 2x time units.  If nothing is received, the node declares itself to be "mode1" and adds that to its message.  If there's a collision & 2 nodes claim to be mode1, they can play [Rock-Paper-Scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors) to figure it out.
3. Other nodes starting up can ask the mode1 node which mode they are.
4. If "mode1" fails to broadcast for 2x time units, "mode2" promotes itself to "mode1" then picks a new "mode2" from all the other nodes.

Comment: Seems like an interesting approach. I'll try it out probably. That said, you had some pretty good grad school projects